# (Lua) How do I increment a variable every time one of three if statements runs?

Tags: lua

I'm building a moving and sensing bot in CoppelliaSim for school.  CopelliaSim uses Lua for scripting.  Basically every time the bot's forward sensors hit something, one of three if statements will run.  I want it to count how many times any of these if statements runs, and once that count gets to a certain amount (like 20), I'll run something else, which will do the same thing (find collisions, add to the count, reach an amount, and switch back to the first).

```
i=0

result=sim.readProximitySensor(noseSensor) -- Read the proximity sensor
-- If we detected something, we set the backward mode:
if (result>0) then backUntilTime=sim.getSimulationTime()+3 
   print("Collision Detected")
   i=i+1
   print(i)
end 

result=sim.readProximitySensor(noseSensor0) -- Read the proximity sensor
-- If we detected something, we set the backward mode:
if (result>0) then backUntilTime=sim.getSimulationTime()+3 
   print("Collision Detected") 
   i=i+1
   print(i)
end 

result=sim.readProximitySensor(noseSensor1) -- Read the proximity sensor
-- If we detected something, we set the backward mode:
if (result>0) then backUntilTime=sim.getSimulationTime()+3 
   print("Collision Detected") 
   i=i+1
   print(i)
end
```

Above is the start of a function and one of the three If statements. I'm printing just to see if it actually increments.  It is printing, but it is not incrementing (just 1 over and over).  This bot has 3 sensors on it (an if statement for each sensor) and it adds 1 to i for the first collision and ignores the rest, even if it's from the same sensor.  I feel like my problem is just some simple syntax issue with Lua that I don't know and can't find how to properly fix.

I'm happy to provide more code if this little snippet was not sufficient to answer this question.

Comment: Why are you setting `i` back to `0` at the beginning every time?

Comment: Oh I see...that would be the syntax problem I was looking for.  I thought it was running that function until I stopped the simulation.  But it's actually restarting the function every time it runs one of the if statements.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a looping function such as `sysCall_actuation` which is being executed per simulation step. As Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica has already stated, you are setting your variable `i` back to zero every time a simulation step is executed. To achieve your goal, you would have to set your variable to 0 outside your function. There are two appropriate approaches to achieve that:

1. Define the variable outside any function, in the beginning of your file (or before you define any function that uses your variable e.g right before the definition of `sysCall_actuation`).

```lua
-- Beginning of the file.
local i = 0

..

function sysCall_actuation()
    ..
    i = i + 1
    ..
end
```

2. Define your variable in `sysCall_init` function, which is the appropriate approach in CoppeliaSim.

```lua
    function sysCall_init()
        i = 0
        ..
    end
```

Finally, you can use your variable in your `sysCall_actuation` function with basic comparison operations:

```lua
function sysCall_actuation()
    ..
    if i > 20 then
        i = 0 -- Reset 'i' so this function will not be running every step again and again.
        -- Do something here.
    ..
end
```

As a side note, practice using local variables whenever you can, to keep the memory clean and avoid having ambiguous variables.